# Why is vapor cloud deploy failing?

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor

My vapor 4.0.0 xCode 11.4 web server runs fine on localhost:8080. When I check the vapor version at the command line, I get 3.1.10, and when I try to deploy, it fails:

```
$ vapor version
Vapor Toolbox: 3.1.10
    $ swift --version
    Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0

    $ vapor cloud deploy
    app: pg3a
  ...
    Selected swift version: 5.2.0 [Failed]
    Swift version 5.2.0 is not supported
    Error: deploy failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Vapor Cloud shut down on Feb 29, 2020.

See archive.org [https://docs.vapor.cloud/shutdown/](https://web.archive.org/web/20200104031144/https://docs.vapor.cloud/shutdown/)

> We are sad to announce that Vapor Cloud will be shutting down on February 29th.
>
> For more information on the shutdown, including guides for migrating to other platforms, please visit our docs.
>
> Going forward, the Vapor core team will be concentrating its efforts on the framework and all of its open source packages. This includes new, free guides for deploying to platforms like Amazon Web Services, Digital Ocean, and Heroku.

Some current information for Vapor 4 deployment can be found at https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/ in the `Deploy` section.